# Spring JPA 5.0.6: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

(I know this question has been asked before but never for Spring 5.x)

I have just picked up a large Spring application and got the task to upgrade from Spring 3.2.16 to 5.0.6. As part of that I am also changing our OpenJpa to Hibernate because OpenJPA is not supported by Spring anymore (and version 3 is not released yet so it seems).

so, my dependencies are

- *Spring* 5.0.6.RELEASE
- *hibernate-jpa-2.1-api*  1.0.0.Final
- *hibernate-core*  5.3.1.Final

I am receiving the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:101)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
```

Configuration looks like

```
    <bean id="ums.entityManagerFactory" 
          class="com.company.package.HibernateJPAEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="persistenceDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ums"/>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/ums-persistence.xml" />
    </bean>

<bean id="persistenceDataSource" 
      class="com.company.package.AutoDriverBasicDataSource">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:data/persistence/persistence" />
    <property name="username" value="<username>" />
    <property name="password" value="<password>" />
</bean>
```

In the setDataSource of our entiyManager we set a *new HibernateJpaDialect()* and new *HibernateJpaVendorAdapter()*.

The *hibernate-core* dependency has the package *org.hibernate.ejb* but no class *HibernatePersistence*.

Comment: may you post the code of your `HibernateJPAEntityManagerFactoryBean`?

Comment: HibernatePersistence is part of hibernate-entitymanager package. Add this to your dependencies.

Comment: In this version of hibernate it says that hibernate-entitymanager has been merged into hibernate-core... but this class is missing. I cannot mix the versions (i.e. I tried to include hibernate-entitymanager  3.4.0.GA)  because I am getting NoSuchMethodErrors  all over the place